# How to remove the window border (containing minimize, maximize and close buttons) from a Qt widget?

Tags: qt, button, maximize

I would like to animate a widget (QPushButon) to move across my application screen. For that I create a new button and using the QPropertyAnimation class and the property "geometry" of the button, I move it from top to down. The problem is that the button comes with the close, minimize, maximize buttons, etc. I don't want them to be there, nor the border that comes with the widget. What should I do ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want to use the function [`QWidget::setWindowFlags( Qt::WindowFlags )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop).

If you want to remove the maximize/minimize/close buttons, this should work for you:

`setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );`

`Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` turns off all the default window hints, like the maximize, minimize, close buttons, and the title bar.

Here's a [list of all `Qt::WindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).

Comment: `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` might be a good option too as this removes the border too. Of course this is only an option provided the button is only to be moved programmatically and not by the user.