# What to do if isTranslucencyCapable is not supported

Tags: java, swing

On our Centos 6.0 box I am trying to have a translucent window with a simple message on it. The ideas is to stop the user entering any data with the program that my program is connected to is stopped. However when I try it with OpenJdk 6 the AWTUtilities code fails with an exception. If I try the code presented as example in this entry [Java transparent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844927/java-transparent-window) all I get is a purple window with a panel with curved corners and it isn't translucent.  Any ideas how I would achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do.  If you already have a JFrame/JDialog on the screen, you could use the [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) instead

Comment: That where I was heading towards. I guess even if I went to OpenJdk 7 which is supposed to support this feature there is no guarantee that the rest of the Centos system would support it?

Comment: No, there's no guarantees that transparency is supported on any system.  The best you can do is provide fail over support :P