# Always On Top Window that stays on top even while showing full screen flash video

Tags: java, linux, swing, user-interface, ubuntu

I am trying to write a simple `subtitle player application` for Ubuntu 12.04 that stays on top even while playing a flash video in full-screen. This application will be similar to [Greenfish Subtitle Player](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Greenfish-Subtitle-Player.shtml) which works wonderfully in Windows.

My question is how do I do this? I was trying a snippet with Java (listed below, I got it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845513/951640) and modified to include `setAlwaysOnTop()`) that makes the JFrame stay on top but not when the flash video is made full screen. My code:

```
import java.awt.*; //Graphics2D, LinearGradientPaint, Point, Window, Window.Type;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * From JavaMagazine May/June 2012
 * @author josh
 */
public class ShapedAboutWindowDemo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //switch to the right thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("About box");
                //turn of window decorations
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                //turn off the background
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                frame.setContentPane(new AboutComponent());
                frame.pack();
                //size the window
                frame.setSize(500, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //center on screen
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
        );
    }

    private static class AboutComponent extends JComponent {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;

            //create a translucent gradient
            Color[] colors = new Color[]{
                           new Color(0,0,0,0)
                            ,new Color(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,1f)
                            ,new Color(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,1f)
                            ,new Color(0,0,0,0)};
            float[] stops = new float[]{0,0.2f,0.8f,1f};
            LinearGradientPaint paint = new LinearGradientPaint(
                                        new Point(0,0), new Point(500,0),
                                        stops,colors);
            //fill a rect then paint with text
            g.setPaint(paint);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 200);
            g.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("My Killer App", 200, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me if this is possible in Ubuntu/Linux and if yes, how. I am open to switch to any other language if it is not possible using Java.

Comment: Using native Java, I don't think you can.  You might need to get access direct to the OS via JNA/JNI. The problem you face is generally when an application is full screen, it usually has exclusive control of the screen