# How to use my custom minimize/close window buttons in my QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qmainwindow

I would like to remove the windows title bar (and minimize/maximize/close buttons) of my QMainWindow. And I would like to use my own minimize/close buttons.

I know how to remove minimize/maximize/close window buttons. It's not a problem.
[How to remove the window border (containing minimize, maximize and close buttons) from a Qt widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948441/how-to-remove-the-window-border-containing-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons)

The problem is to add those new buttons (minimize/close). Is it possible to do that in Qt Style Sheet (or in C++) ?

ps: I would like something portable for Windows/Mac/Linux

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39821779/2666212). I think that this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that kind of decoration depends on the windows manager. You may find OS dependant solutions ([this for Windows](http://www.it-quants.com/Blogs/tabid/83/EntryId/53/Win32-SDK-how-to-change-the-title-bar-color-title.aspx) changes other aspects of the title bar, for example), but if you remove the window buttons, then the only portable option I know is to create your own *container window*, a `QWidget` that has a header region with the buttons you want and a `centralWiget` where you can add the rest of you application:

[image]

You then connect header buttons

```
connect(m_ui.btnMinimize, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(showMinimized()));
connect(m_ui.btnClose, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(close()));
```

To make it reusable, just add an `insert(QWidget*)` method to replace the `centralWidget`.

*Note:* take into consideration that you must create the container with the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag set, therefore if you want to allow the user to move/resize the window, you must take care of those actions manually too.

Answer (score 1):

You should create window without system bar (without minimize, full-screen, close buttons you can use the next flags for that Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint) and add your own customized system buttons.